# Symfony 4 doctrine yaml mappng

Tags: doctrine-orm, mapping, yaml, symfony4

I use yaml mapping

And when I try `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities App --no-backup`, I  get the error

> Can't find base path for "App\Entity\User"

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4

        # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: 'yml'
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/doctrine'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: 'App'
```

Sample User.orm.yml:

```
App\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: tbl_user
    repositoryClass: App\Entity\UserRepository

    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 40
            nullable: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: 40
            nullable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This command is provided by the [sensio/generator-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/sensio/generator-bundle#dev-master), which is not compatible with Symfony 4, and will never be.

On the readme file, they advice to use the [MakeBundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle) instead.

But it seems there no equivalent for the generate:entities command. In most of IDE (I'm using PhpStorm), there is helper to generate getter and setter.

Comment: So bad. I need to generate from yaml and change database tables.